# JAXB Without Defining Class or Annotations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I would like to use JAXB to read and write only a few parts of a very large XML. I would like to be able to do this without having to define a root object class for every element and attribute in the XML. The example below outlines what I need:

I have the XML

```xml
<A>
  <B/>
  <C/>
  <D/>
</A>
```

I would like to use JAXB to get two functions

```java
public String getC() {
    ...    
    return C
}

public void writeC(String C) {
    ... // replaces C value with the paramter C inside the XML
}
```

Without having to define a new class A with the annotations for B, C, and D.

How can I do this with JAXB? Is there a faster / more efficient way to achieve what I am trying to do than JAXB or a simple File Reader and Writer?

The purpose of this is to use a GUI to load and edit config settings that are stored in an XML file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using StAX instead. It offered complete flexibility for me to pick out which tags and which attrbitues I needed.

Comment: This actually does not answer the question. It describes how you solved your problem but cannot be considered the correct answer to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called [EclipseLink MOXy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) that could solve this type of problem using JAXB. It allows you to map an existing java bean to or from xml and define exceptions from default JAXB using xml or json for the mapping description.